# Comparing 2 dates to the current date and make active or expired

Tags: php, date

I am trying to work out I have 2 dates and I want to have them compared to todays date. If both dates are greater that today make status active else expired.
If 1 date is greater (active) and the other is less than today it should change to expired. Here is my code. I cannot get this to work correctly. I cannot work out what I am missing

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate));

$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("22/10/2021"));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("23/08/2021"));

if (($date1 > $currentDate) && ($date2 > $currentDate)) {
    echo "Active";
} else {
    echo "Expired";
}
```

Comment: A simple `var_dump($currentDate, $date1, $date2);` would have brought you some clarity already.

Comment: And `$currentDate = date('Y-m-d'); $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate));` makes little sense. "Hello, I have a date value in Y-m-d format here, could you please parse this into a timestamp, and then format it as Y-m-d for me?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't respect the `'Y-m-d'` format. You want to convert your dates to `'Y-m-d'`, but you passed them as `'d/m/Y'`.

Try to change your lines :

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("22/10/2021"));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("23/08/2021"));
```

by :

```
 $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2021-10-22"));
 $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2021-08-23"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In php strtime() documentation:

The best way to compensate for this is by modifying your joining characters. Forward slash (/) signifies American M/D/Y formatting, a dash (-) signifies European D-M-Y and a period (.) signifies ISO Y.M.D.

**Observe:**

```
<?php
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11.12.10"));
// outputs 10th December, 2011
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11/12/10"));
// outputs 12th November, 2010
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11-12-10"));
// outputs 11th December, 2010 
?>
```

**So:**
change your date formate in strtime() function like this

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
  $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate));

  $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("10/22/2021"));
  $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("08/23/2021"));

  if (($date1 > $currentDate) && ($date2 > $currentDate))
  {
      echo "Active";
  }else{
      echo "Expired";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try this

```
<?php

$currentDate = date('Y-m-d'); 
$currentDate = date(strtotime($currentDate));

$date1 = new DateTime();
$date1->setDate(2021, 10, 22);
$date1 = $date1->getTimestamp();

$date2 = new DateTime();
$date2->setDate(2021, 8, 23);
$date2 = $date2->getTimestamp();

if (($date1 > $currentDate) && ($date2 > $currentDate)) {

    echo "Active";
}
else {

    echo "Expired";
}


?>
```